# Gigya SDK - Comments Plugin nicknames

Tags: android, ios, sdk, gigya

I'm having some problems regarding Gigya comments plugin at mobile SDKs. 
I need to display user nicknames instead the default combination "firstname + lastname".

Did anyone know how can I change the user names displayed in the Gigya's comments plugin?

I've tryed the "templates" option that might work in a normal js call of module but does nothing on mobile SDKs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Gigya comments plug-in will use the user's "displayname" parameter if it is set.   If it is not set, then it will revert to using "Firstname Lastname".  If you want the user's nickname to appear in the comments plug-in, then you should ensure that the "displayname" parameter is also populated with the user's nickname.

You can programmatically set the user's *diplayname* when they login if it is empty, by making a call to [accounts.setAccountInfo](http://developers.gigya.com/037_API_reference/020_Accounts/accounts.setAccountInfo) that sets the *displayname* to the *nickname*.

As long as the *displayname* has a value on the account, then it will be used by the plugin.  There is no other logic from the perspective of the Gigya comments plugin you should need, since this is handled from data in the account itself.

Comment: Thanks again for another fix and explanation.